# Sludge filling the bottom of Kenmore Water Softener

Tags: plumbing, water, water-softener

Kenmore UltraSoft 425

[image: water softener]

The water softener tank was filled to the top with water. I cleaned the Venturi and put it back on. I jiggled the float valve and ran the recharge. I came back, and it was empty to almost the bottom, but the bottom of the tank had this mush of salt with some brown.

[image: tank]

Is there an easy way to clean this out? Should I be concerned? I'm waiting to fill it up with new salt. I'm about to go to a store and see if I can find a shovel that will fit down there to dig it all out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have better luck with a wet vacuum cleaner. You can get them at your home store and you'll find all sorts of uses for it after you get one. They have narrow attachments that will suck all that stuff out of there. Looks like the tank hasn't been cleaned in a while.